# Setting two properties of StreetViewPanorama causes race condition?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I'm using Street View's javascript api to open views of particular locations.  I want the viewer to be both at a certain point, and facing in a certain direction, so I have this call (as in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewServiceResponses)):

```
panorama.setOptions({
    pano: data.location.pano,
    pov: mypov
});
```

I think that the image fetches from fulfilling the two options must get interleaved or something, because about half the time the screen ends up a mosaic of more than one image:

[image: Jumbled image made up of random tiles from the same location]

When I comment out `setPov`, of course the view is facing in the wrong direction, but the overlapping image tile problem is gone.  Also, as soon as the user starts a mouse drag, the street view settles on the correct image tiles and throws away the incorrect ones.

Is there any way to prevent this?  Or is there an "all the images are loaded" event I can listen for, and then trigger a drag event or something?

**Edit**: Here is a jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/p244m3qp/11/
In my browser, if I stretch the "result" pane as large as possible, it displays the "mosaic" behavior about 1/3 to 1/2 of the animation frames.

Comment: I don't see the issue.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Fair enough!  Just added one.  `.setOptions()` was a really good idea, but unfortunately it still happens even then (as in the jsfiddle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to prevent your error.
http://jsfiddle.net/wf9a5m75/p244m3qp/31/

Key point is that preload the streetview in background.

At the first, you need to create two panorama divs.

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=en"></script>
<div id="err"></div>
<div id="pv-container">
  <div id="backscreen"></div>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
```

The <div id="map-canvas"/> overlaps <div id="backscreen"/> completely with CSS.

```
#pv-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
#map-canvas {
  border: solid thick #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#backscreen {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: solid thick red;
}
```

You need to change the panorama position (pano and pov) for the background first, then set to the map-canvas div.
For that time, you need to change the heading (or might be pitch) of background.
This generates cache images inside the Google Maps API (I guess).

```
function initialize() {
  var loc = {
      lat: 38.9002138,
      lng: -77.0364319
    },
    pov = {
      heading: 180,
      pitch: -5
    },
    svService = new google.maps.StreetViewService(),
    panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
            document.getElementById('map-canvas')),
    backscreen = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
            document.getElementById('backscreen')),
    counter = 0;

  function updatePano(data, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
        var opts = {
        pano: data.location.pano,
        pov: {heading: pov.heading + 120 * (counter % 3), pitch: pov.pitch}
      };
      backscreen.setOptions(opts);
      backscreen.changed = function(key) {
        if (key === 'status' && backscreen.get('status') === 'OK') {
          var opts2 = Object.create(opts);
          opts2.heading += 5;
            backscreen.setOptions(opts2);
          setTimeout(function() {
                panorama.setOptions(opts);
          }, 100);

        }
      }
    } else {
      document.getElementById('err').textContent = "Failed to get panorama";
    }
    counter = (counter + 1) % 15;
  }

  setInterval(function() {
    svService.getPanorama({
      location: {
        lat: loc.lat + (counter * 0.0001),
        lng: loc.lng
      },
      radius: 35
    }, updatePano);
  }, 3000);

}

initialize();
```

[image]

You may be interested in what happens in the background div.
Here it is:
[image]

Comment: Wow, crazy!  I will try it later this week & give you the bounty if it works!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @wf9a5m75 didn't quite work for me but it led me in the right direction, and this ended up working in Chrome:  I replaced the single call

```
panorama.setOptions({
    pano: data.location.pano,
    pov: mypov
});
```

with two calls that are forced to be serial:

```
panorama.setPano(pano);
panorama.changed = function(key) {
    if (key === 'status') {
        // Just listen once!
        panorama.changed = function() {};
        panorama.setPov(mypov);
   }
};
```

So loading takes twice as long, but at least it doesn't look horrible...

**Edit:** looks like this is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5837) - seems like you can make the race condition hit less often, but not really prevent it. :(

Comment: Thank for the update. I did not that is fired as known bug.